# How to calculate sprint chart for scrum project

Tags: scrum, burndowncharts

I know something about scrum and project management. For ex. We need to findout all steps of program and write down with their prioraty and work hours. But I don't know how to draw burn down chart for one sprint (which values do we need and which calculation creates the chart?).

[image]

Comment: I think this question is begging for you to read the Scrum Guide!! :)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

- the duration of the sprint (in days). This is the x-axis.
- the sum of all task-durations within a sprint. This is the y-axis.

Now you can calculate the ideal-line. On the first day no task is accomplished. On the last day all tasks should be accomplished.

The chart draws the task-hours that are not accomplished for each day.

That's it.

Comment: +1 Good answer. One thing to add is the y-axis is typically estimated hours. (during Sprint Planning)

Comment: I've normally seen them estimated in "points" rather than hours, with the velocity of the previous sprint helping us work out how many points we can play in this sprint. @uzay95, if your team is new to Scrum don't be too surprised if you find you don't track the line very well to start with. Lumpy lines are OK; I'd concentrate on finishing the stories and getting feedback rather than worrying too much about velocity and estimation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a whole tutorial I wrote up on managing burn down charts including a google docs template and a microsoft excel template

http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/burn-down-charts-tutorial-simple-agile-project-tracking/

Answer (score 1):

> which values do we need and which calculation creates the chart?

I guess crauscher already answered this question but I just wanted to say that there are tons of tools out there which can create the burndown for you automatically. All your Team has to do is enter and burn down hours during the Sprint. Although Agile suggests to prefer interactions and use less tools, if you really want to scale as a project/company you would need some sort of Agile project management software. A few I can recommend are : Scrumworks, Piviotal Tracker, Agilex.